# Force Entity Framework to read each line with all details

Tags: entity-framework

I am having trouble with en EF method returning duplicate rows of data. When I am running this, in my example, it returns four rows from a database view. The fourth row includes details from the third row.

The same query in SSMS returns four individual rows with the correct details. I have read somewhere about EK and problems with optimization when there are no identity column. But - is there anyway to alter the below code to force EK to read all records with all details?

```
public List<vs_transactions> GetTransactionList(int cID)
{
    using (StagingDataEntities db = new StagingDataEntities())
    {
        var res = from trans in db.vs_transactions
                  where trans.CreditID == cID 
                  orderby trans.ActionDate descending
                  select trans;

        return res.ToList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution :) MergeOption.NoTracking

```
    public List<vs_transactions> GetTransactionList(int cID)
    {
        db.vs_transactions.MergeOption = MergeOption.NoTracking;

        using (StagingDataEntities db = new StagingDataEntities())
        {
            var res = from trans in db.vs_transactions
                      where trans.CreditID == cID 
                      orderby trans.ActionDate descending
                      select trans;
    
            return res.ToList();
        }
    }
```